# Sorting array based on index of minimum value?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm currently trying to learn C, and the exercise I found online has me creating a function that returns the index of the smallest value in an array. This is my function:

```
int return_index_of_minimum(int A[10], int i, int j){
    int minimum_value = A[i];
    int index_to_return = 0;
    for (int index = i; index < j; index++){
        if (A[index] < minimum_value){
            minimum_value = A[index];
            index_to_return = index;
        }
    }
return index_to_return;
}
```

i and j are the lower and upper bound numbers the function should look in. For example, if i is 4 and j is 8, that means the function will return the index of the smallest value between indices 4 and 8.

Here is my main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int numbers[10];
    int user_input = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &user_input);
        numbers[i] = user_input;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int index_of_min_value = return_index_of_minimum(numbers, i, 10);
        int old_num = numbers[index_of_min_value];
        int new_num = numbers[i];

        numbers[index_of_min_value] = new_num;
        new_array[i] = old_num;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d\n", new_array[i]);
    }
}
```

The user would first enter a bunch of numbers and that would populate the array with the user's values. The idea is to use `return_index_of_minimum` to return the index of the smallest item in an array, and then set that equal to `numbers[0]` with a for loop, and then `numbers[1]`, and then so on. `old_num` is the lowest number in the array, at its previous index. Here, I'm trying to swap that minimum value with whatever is at `numbers[i]` However, when I'm done sorting through the entire array, and am printing it out, I see that 10 (when the user enters 1-10 randomly for values) is at index 0, and then the rest of the numbers are in order. Does anybody see what is wrong here?

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. This will help you see what some piece of code *actually* does. :)

Comment: your function `return_index_of_minimum` does not work if the first value is the minimum and `i` is not `0`. Change `int index_to_return = 0;` to `int index_to_return = i;`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite see the error that you're seeing. `int index_to_return=0` is actually just to initialize the variable (unless that isn't necessary). If the first value is the minimum, then wouldn't the loop completely bypass the if statement and return the index at 0?

Comment: What if the value at `A[0]` is *larger* than the value at `A[i]`, but `A[i]` is the smallest in the sub-set you are checking? That means you will not return the index of the smallest value in the set you're checking.

Comment: if you call `return_index_of_minimum(numbers, 2, 10);` and `numbers[2]` is the minimum, it will return `0` instead of `2`.

Comment: @mch Oh I see what you mean now. Okay, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix:

```
int return_index_of_minimum(int A[10], int i, int j){
   int minimum_value = A[i];
   int index_to_return = i;
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't have protection of invalid arguments, but otherwise this is an answer you've been looking for.

The reason is in call `index_of_minimum(a, 9, 10)`: the loop performs only one iteration for `index = 9`, and because the minimum value is already initialized to value `a[9]`, the `index_to_return` is not updated due to condition check.

This is a different approach that doesn't have same issue:

```
int return_index_of_minimum(int A[10], int i, int j){
  /* assuming i < j */
  int minimum_value = A[i];
  int index_to_return = i;  /* First element is a candidate */
  for (int index = i + 1; index < j; index++){
    /* Iterate from second element */
    if (A[index] < minimum_value){
      minimum_value = A[index];
      index_to_return = index;
    }
  }
  return index_to_return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an error in your `return_index_of_minimum` function.

```
int index_to_return = 0;
```

The problem lies I think here as the value of `index_to_return` will stay 0 if you call `return_index_of_minimum(numbers, 5, 10);` and that `numbers[5]` if the actual minimum.

However why not use a simple bubble-sort like the one implemented [here](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-sorting-bubble-sort/)

```
/*
 * C program to sort N numbers in ascending order using Bubble sort
 * and print both the given and the sorted array
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int array[MAXSIZE];
    int i, j, num, temp;

    printf("Enter the value of num \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter the elements one by one \n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Input array is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    /*   Bubble sorting begins */
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (num - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted array is...\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be `int main(void)` and not `void main()`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the typo